# Java - suspend thread until other thread event

Tags: java, multithreading, suspend

I have an object A on which I'm updating some data every second and other objects B and C which want to use the data only once per update.
Every object work in parallel.

How can I make B and C wait for the update in A ?

I've seen some similar questions but their responses didn't help me.
I've seen that I could use a "synchronized" bloc on an object D, but they just put the bloc without telling how to instanciate or share that object.

The following code is what I use for my tests. I managed to get them working in parallel but I'm stuck with the suspending part.

This is the class for A

```
public class Master{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Worker B = new Worker("B");
    B.start();

    Worker C = new Worker("C");
    C.start();

    while(true)
    {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      // update data
      // notify every thread waiting that they can resume
    }
  }
}
```

This is the class used for B and C

```
public class Worker extends Thread
{
  Worker(String name)
  {
    super("Worker " + name);
  }

  public void run()
  {
    int i = 0;
    while(!this.isInterrupted())
    {
      // wait for A to update data
      System.out.println(i);
      i++;
    }
    System.out.println("thread interrupted");
  }
}
```

From there, what do I need to add for the purpose I'm looking for ?

Comment: Have a look at `Object.wait()` and `Object.notify()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it very low level, only using the lang APIs, you should use wait/notifyAll.

Not that I used Main.class as an arbitrary object to synchronize

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SharedData sharedData = new SharedData();
        Worker w1 = new Worker("Worker 1", sharedData);
        Worker w2 = new Worker("Worker 2", sharedData);

        w1.start();
        w2.start();

        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                sharedData.increase();;
                System.out.println("Master: " + sharedData.value());
                synchronized (Main.class) {
                    Main.class.notifyAll();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}

class SharedData {
    private int data = 0;

    public void increase () {
        data++;
    }

    public int value() {
        return data;
    }

}

class Worker extends Thread {
    private String workerName;
    private SharedData sharedData;

    public Worker(String workerName, SharedData sharedData) {
        super();
        this.workerName = workerName;
        this.sharedData = sharedData;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                synchronized (Main.class) {
                    Main.class.wait();
                }
                System.out.println(workerName + ": " + sharedData.value());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what "Main.class" is ? This is the first time I see such thing and from the point of view of Worker, it looks like a global variable (which is something we should try to avoid right ?)

Comment: This case is a global variable. Is an arbitrary lock. You could replace that with the instance of SharedData, or anything that both your Main class and Worker can lock (synchronize) on

Comment: @user3548298: Do you need any more help with this question?

Comment: I have modified it a bit so that my master doesn't run in static and used it as a parameter for the workers constructor and synchronized on it. Now it works just as I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but this might be worth checking out for you:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html

Answer (score -2):

Why use threads at all?  Why not just do this?

```
public class Master {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Worker B = new Worker("B");
        Worker C = new Worker("C");

        while(true) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            updateData();
            B.doWork();
            C.doWork();
        }
    }
}

public class Worker
{
    public void doWork() {
        System.out.println(i);
        i++;
    }

    private int i = 0;
}
```